# xcodebuild fails with #Preview macro with Xcode 15.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

I noticed that in Xcode 15.0, `xcodebuild` command to archive the app fails unless I remove the `#Preview` macro from the app.

```bash
$ xcodebuild archive -scheme <Your Scheme> -sdk iphoneos -allowProvisioningUpdates -archivePath build.xcarchive
```

and the error is:

```
{
  "kind": "finished",
  "name": "compile",
  "pid": 42409,
  "output": "<unknown>:0: warning: compiler plugin not loaded: '\/Applications\/Xcode-15.0.0-Release.Candidate.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/swift-plugin-server; fai
led to initialize\n\/Users\/xyz\/Dev\/experiments\/fastlane-test\/fastlane-test\/ContentView.swift:22:1: error: external macro implementation type 'PreviewsMacros.SwiftUIView' could not be found for macro
'Preview(_:body:)'\n#Preview {\n^\nSwiftUI.Preview:2:41: note: 'Preview(_:body:)' declared here\n@freestanding(declaration) public macro Preview(_ name: String? = nil, body: @escaping @MainActor () -> View) = #ex
ternalMacro(module: \"PreviewsMacros\", type: \"SwiftUIView\")\n                                        ^\n",
  "process": {
    "real_pid": 42409
  },
  "exit-status": 1
}
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

How to reproduce:

1. Create a brand new app project with Xcode 15.0 RC
2. Run the above command

If I comment out the default `#Preview` statement in the `ContentView.swift`, the same command passes flawlessly. What am I missing?

Comment: Xcode 15.0.1 has shipped so I tried with it but the same result. I found "rosetta error: Failed to open libRosettaRuntime" message in the log by the way. Does that sound related? I'm using the M1 mac

Comment: Seeing the same, but only on some machines in our org.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I see. It would depend on the Mac OS version? I'm using `13.5.2 (22G91)`

Comment: No luck on Xcode 15.2.0 yet

Comment: It seems it does not reproduce in Xcode 15.3. How about you guys?

Comment: By the way, I upgraded macOS to 14.4 lately. So, it could also be the reason though

Answer (score 0):

Not really a full solution, but this command allowed me to get past the same issue:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipMacroFingerprintValidation -bool YES
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. I also tried `-skipMacroValidation` option but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your Terminal in running in Rosetta (i386) mode.

You can test this out by running

```
> arch
```

which will probably return

```
i386
```

To switch architectures:

```
> arch -arm64 /bin/zsh
```

then

```
> arch
```

should show

```
arm64
```

Then your `xcodebuild` should work as expected

You can also check the info on your Terminal app and it'll probably be set to "Open using Rosetta":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I saw it for the first time, I was sure that was the case. But I can't confirm now it was it since the issue seems to be gone with the Xcode 15.3 (or macOS version issue) even with the `i386` arch. So, if people still use the Xcode 15.2 or prior, I'm glad if you could verify the Ashley's answer so that I can accept this as an correct answer.